# SQLite to Number Rows by Two Criteria

Tags: sql, sqlite, row-number

I want to use sqlite to number rows in a csv file by two criteria: Duplicate Id number and Created Date. (I am analyzing duplicate account data generated by DemandTools.) Just to help explain, here is a simplified version of what I want to do:

Want to turn this:

```
Dupe Id #  |   Account Name   |   Created Date  |
1882       | A1, Inc.         |  03/15/2015     |
1567       | Joe's Plumbing   |  08/01/2019     |
1567       | Joes plubming    |  02/07/2020     |
1882       | A1 Corporation   |  06/20/2019     |
1882       | A1 Incorporated  |  05/16/2016     |
```

Into this:

```
Dupe Id #  |   Account Name   |   Created Date  |   Dupe #   |
1567       | Joe's Plumbing   |  08/01/2019     |   0        |
1567       | Joes plubming    |  02/07/2020     |   1        |
1882       | A1, Inc.         |  03/15/2015     |   0        |
1882       | A1 Incorporated  |  05/16/2016     |   1        |
1882       | A1 Corporation   |  06/20/2019     |   2        |
```

I want the original account to have a value of 0, the first dupe 1, 2nd dupe 2, etc.

I had a way to do this in excel using a multi column sort and a countif function like this =COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)-1, but what was working in excel for 100k rows and 10 columns, is not working with 700k rows and 24 columns.

My SQLite knowledge is currently at a beginner level. I understand the basics, but not really sure where to begin with a problem like this. I know how to sort by a single column in SQLite, but I don't know how to deal with the countif part of the problem (and maybe there is a better way with SQLite?).

Any help is much appreciated . . . .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing you must do is change the format of your dates to `YYYY-MM-DD` because this is the only valid format for dates in SQLite and it is comparable.
With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select *,
  row_number() over (partition by Id order by CreatedDate) - 1 Dupe
from tablename 
order by id, Dupe
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwiqMErafsBb7U7rfHL2Z/1).
Results:

```
| Id   | AccountName     | CreatedDate | Dupe |
| ---- | --------------- | ----------- | ---- |
| 1567 | Joe's Plumbing  | 2019-08-01  | 0    |
| 1567 | Joes plubming   | 2020-02-07  | 1    |
| 1882 | A1, Inc.        | 2015-03-15  | 0    |
| 1882 | A1 Incorporated | 2016-05-16  | 1    |
| 1882 | A1 Corporation  | 2019-06-20  | 2    |
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help. I forgot to mention that I plan to import the csv data directly into an SQLite database. Will this change things at all? (I'm thinking I will reformat the CreatedDate column into the format you've shown in excel prior to import.)

Comment: As I ment ion in my question the only valid date format is `YYYY-MM-DD` so you must change the format or you will not be able to directly compare and sort dates. About the Dupe column there is no need to have it stored in the table. It is a derived column. When you need it use the expression: `row_number() over (partition by Id order by CreatedDate) - 1` in a query.